# Resizing the boot partition - Windows Server 2003

Tags: windows-server-2003

I'm using Windows Server 2003 in my machine. I've a meager 60 MB free space in C (system drive) and I've 8 GB in D drive. Is there any possibility that I can resize the C drive to add 6 GB taken from the consequent D drive?

Thank you
NLV

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Get the GPartEd live-CD at http://gparted.sourceforge.net/livecd.php
2. Burn it to a CD, boot with it
3. Resize the Partitions
4. Done!

Comment: Do i need to do any backups? Will lose any data? Thank you.

Comment: @NLV You should always have a backup that can recover your system to a point and\or within a timescale that you can live with, but especially when messing with the boot partition of a system.

Comment: I've done that a few times with no problems, but still, backup is always recommended!

Answer (score 1):

You can always mount the 8 GB partition on the d drive as a folder on the c: drive and move files to it, effectively adding space to the c: drive without downtime or potential loss of data. If you had free contiguous space on the same physical disk you could simply extend the partition using diskpart.  If it's not contiguous you'd have to do some shuffling around (which would incur some downtime and backups).  If you choose to use the gparted tool be aware that it can (and from experience it has) completly scrambled partitions that are on raid controllers, and currently it is not reccomended to use the latest version of gparted on ntfs systems (use 0.4.6.1) if you cannot use the native tools.